# Adding holes to this sphere

Tags: edit-mode

I would like to subtract cylindrical holes in this object, centered over each of the highlighted vertices and aligned with the object's center.  Can somebody show me how to do this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to bse. Could you please post a [sample file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) or link on how to create quad sphere like that.

Comment: A similar sphere, if this can help: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4695" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4695/)

Comment: What do you mean by "cylindrical holes"? Just a cut or plain tubes?

Comment: Thank you both for answering so quickly!  LukeD and remco.   I'm new to blender and relatively new to 3d modeling.  You guys rock!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Steps:

First of all activate LoopTools add-on in User Preferences, than:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to **Bevel** vertices.
2. <kbd>MouseWheel</kbd> to add more cuts or press <kbd>F6</kbd> to see menu with **Bevel** options.
3. <kbd>W</kbd> **> LoopTools > Circle**.
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Num -</kbd>  to select less.
5. <kbd>X</kbd> > **Delete Vertices**.

[image: steps]

### Edit:

For OP model holes will have different number of vertices. But besides that everything is working just fine.

[image: edit]

As a workaround you can first select vertices with 3 connected edges and make for example 5 Bevel cuts: 3 edges x 5 cuts = 15 vertices.

Than do the same thing with vertices with 5 edges connected with 3 cuts: 5 edges x 3 cuts = 15 vertices.

Comment: I'm afraid Ctrl+Shift+B will not work as expected for the OP's model, as the selected vertices are not surrounded by the same amount of edges.

Comment: @lemon check my edit.

Comment: LukeD, right. But Steve should tell what he means by "cylindrical" as I understand it as "plain tubes"... but I don't know

Comment: @lemon well, we will need to wait for Steve to answer. No matter what it could be a couple of steps more.

Comment: LukeD, anyway your solution is probably ok as facing vertices share the same amount of edges... so you can bridge them... UV for your answer!

Comment: Yes.  Plain tubes.  Well it worked great.  You can make sure that the resultant shape faces have the same vertices the same diameter by typing in a value for radius when you do the loop function.  After deleting vertices inside the circles I simply extruded the faces of the circles inward.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate only the selected vertices and separate them into their own object (S2).
Create the cylinder of the required diameter and length. Make it a child of S2 and set 'Duplication->verts' on S2 (check the "rotation" box). You may have to realign the cylinder and correct its length, I found that that works best in edit mode.
Make the duplicates real (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>) (perhaps join them in a single object to ease the next step).
Now use a boolean modifier on your first object and subtract the cylinders you created

Comment: This approach may be interesting but as an answer you should provide more details and eventually the corresponding blend file. I say that mainly because the boolean modifier may or not work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just adding a little bit of info.

I tried to solve this procedurally using Sverchok Add-On in Blender. Basically as you requested, if you want to place Cylinder at every selected points, then boolean it. In such scenario, if you do this often, you might want to use Python code or node setup like this.

I found that we need to have a thickness on the icosphere so that we can have a nice boolean cut.